# Contact form HTML mail styling

Tags: php, html, email, html-email, styling

I'm currently trying to style incoming emails that are sent via my self made php contact form.

There is only one slight problem, when i receive the e-mail in my inbox, the html is displayed as static text instead of code.

Anyone who can help me out?

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: info@epicconcepts.nl'; 
$to = 'info@epicconcepts.nl'; 
$subject = 'Contact formulier bericht';
$human = $_POST['human'];

$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: quincynorbert@live.nl\r\n";
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$message = '<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
            <style type="text/css">
                body{background: #EDEBEA;}
                #naam{background:#222222;border:4px solid #DDD;width:650px;}
                #mail{background:#222222;border:4px solid #DDD;width:650px;}
                #message{background:#222222;border:4px solid #DDD;width:650px;}
            </style>
            </head>
            <body>
            <div id="naam">'.$name.'</div>
            <div id="mail">'.$email.'</div>
            <div id="message">'.$message.'</div>
            </body>
            </html>';

if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if ($name != '' && $email != '') {
        if ($human == '4') {                 
            if (mail ($to, $subject, $message, $from)) { 
            echo '<p class="correct-message">Your message has been sent!</p>';
        } else { 
            echo '<p class="correct-message">Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
        } 
    } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
        echo '<p class="correct-message">You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
    }
    } else {
        echo '<p class="correct-message">You need to fill in all required fields!</p>';
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks for in the advance

Comment: Just a sidenote: You should NOT format your mail using html/head/body/css/divs. Many email-readers have huge problems with this. You should construct it in tables and images. Ugly as heck, but it works everywhere. I recommend googling around on this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your headers are contained in the string `$headers` but you don't pass that to the mail function, you are passing `$from` so the HTML and MIME headers are never sent which is why you get a plain text email:

```
if (mail ($to, $subject, $message, $from)) {
//                                 ^ should be $headers
```

Change to:

```
if (mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
```

Also, your MIME header erases the current list of headers because you didn't include the concatenation `.` character, change to:

```
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
//       ^ don't forget this
```

Finally, you should avoid using `<style>` CSS blocks in HTML emails, not all email clients will read CSS blocks, some will only read the CSS if it's defined inline with a `style=""` attribute directly on the element.

Edit: to hardcode your From header just use:

```
$headers = "From: info@mycompany.com\r\n";
```

Be sure to fix the concatenation error that I pointed out above, otherwise your `From` header will be overwritten and not sent.

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem is gone, but now when i receive a e-mail the from bar says unknown, is it possible to add headers, and from?

Comment: Is `$_POST['req-email']` being populated? should it be `$_POST['email']`? Try hard coding a value instead of using a post variable. This is better anyway because it avoids header injection vulnerabilities. Plus you will get inconsistent results in terms of spam filters if you use the visitor's email address as the from header.

Comment: Okay, i think i know what you mean, if from is email, it would mean it will always be the email adress the customer entered in the form. My last question is how i could make in hard coded, because Just typing my company name there doesnt have any effect. Your help is greatly appreciated! Thank you very much!

Comment: See my edit for how to hardcode the `From` header. Did you fix the concatenation error on the MIME header? Because if not, the `From` header will be overwritten.

Comment: MrCode, your help is greatly appreciated, i managed to do the last step my self but it all worked out, as mentioned before, thank you very much, this was an all night struggle :)Keep up the good work!